# How to use a different/specific 'teardown method' withing a testrun based on the type of test

Tags: testng

I'm creating a testing framework which tests both the UI of the application and the REST API's it uses. So for example after performing a REST GET call I check if the data that is returned matches the data in the UI and after a successful post (initiated by the UI test) I will check the data by doing another GET call and compare the data. 
I'm using Java with TestNG, Selenium and will (probably) use REST Assured.

I'm kinda new to TestNG, but how can I perform different teardown actions based on the type of test that is run? For the UI test for example I'm taking a screenshot when the test fails, but for a failing REST test that obviously serves no point and there I want to capture the request and response and add that info to the report.

I'm still in the process of thinking the framework through, so I don't have relevant code to share, but this is such a generic question that is nagging me that I hope you guys can answer without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've fixed this by creating a custom annotation (@UITest). In the TestNG @beforeClass I check what methods have the @UITest annotation and add those to a list.

```
@BeforeClass
public void getUiTestMethods() {
    Method[] methods = getClass().getMethods();
    for (Method method: methods) {
        if(method.isAnnotationPresent(UiTest.class)) {
            UiTestMethods.add(method.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

In the @afterClass (teardown) method I then use the methodname I get from ITestResult and check if that method is in the list created in the @beforeClass.

```
if (UiTestMethods.contains(result.getMethod().getMethodName())) {
                // do stuff
}
```

This way I can differentiate the handling of a failed test.
It may not be the best/cleanest way to do it, but at least it works.

If anyone has a better suggestion I'm still open for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it via **@AfterGroups** annotation